# How to merge the 2 variables so the header render when using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

bear with me as I started Python few days ago, I'm trying to get the bellow formating right but cannot figure out how to do that,

I'm trying to format some information back from my networking gear, using TextFSM I manage to get extract the information I need, I want to use Pandas to create an excel sheet so it's formatted properly

below the output picture

[image]

as I said I use TextFSM, so the variable re_table contain my header for each column ( re_table.header ) here is the output:

```
['port', 'Address', 'Ipaddress', 'Plateform']
```

my dataframe for Pandas contains the right information see bellow, however are display without the header

```
    0                  1               2          3
0  46  98 f2 b3 4e 7c b0  172.27.254.212  HP J9774A
1  48                     172.27.254.210  Cisco IOS
2  48  24 e9 b3 a0 c8 80  172.27.254.210  Cisco IOS
```

I want to merge the 2 in order to generate the Excel sheet with the header for my column, so far I'm not able to sort this out

I believe it's just a matter of concataining the code but I'm unable to figure out

```
def cdp():
    out = conn.send_command("show cdp neighbors detail")
    print(out)
    raw_text_data = out
    template = open("/root/ntc-templates/templates/hp_procurve_show_cdp_multiple.template")
    re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
    fsm_results = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data)
    cdp_result = re_table.header + fsm_results
    outfile_name = open("outfile.csv", "w+")
    outfile = outfile_name
    print(re_table.header)
    for s in re_table.header:
        outfile.write("%s," % s)
    outfile.write("\n")
    counter = 0
    for row in fsm_results:
        print(row)
        for s in row:
            outfile.write("%s," % s)
        outfile.write("\n")
        counter += 1
    print("Write %d records" % counter)
    print('Importing CDP info to a more structured way')
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fsm_results) # transpose the tables so interfaces are in a column
    #dataframe.sort_values(by=['port'], inplace=True) # sort the values by the "port" column we made
    #dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index to match this
    #dfColumns = dataframe.columns.tolist()
    #dataframe = dataframe[dfColumns]
    dataframe.to_excel('/root/'+ 'test.xls',index=False)
    print(re_table.header)
    print(dataframe)
```

I now need to merge the 2 Dataframe on the final script, here is the current df structure of the main script

```
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(interfaceDict).T # transpose the tables so interfaces are in a column
    dataframe.sort_values(by=['port'], inplace=True) # sort the values by the "port" column we made
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index to match this


    # we want to re-order the columns, so we pull the names into a list
    dfColumns = dataframe.columns.tolist()

    # we change the order so that the "port" column header is first
    dfColumns.insert(0, dfColumns.pop(2))
    # then we re-insert that topology into the dataframe
    dataframe = dataframe[dfColumns]


    # finally we can export as an excel document
    dataframe.to_excel('/root/' + hostname + '.xls',index=False)
```

I need to merge the Dataframe "fsm_results", if that help the Column header Port is the same as the primary Dataframe

here is the structure of the primary Dataframe:

```
port    mode    onlineCount status  vlan100 vlan101 vlan111 vlan118 vlan3000    vlan69  vlan805 vlan806 vlan851 vlan906
```

the vlan will always vary base on the switch, hence why port is the best way to merge the data, full code is here for you to see the full code if that help: https://pastebin.com/42uH55pL

the best way would be to insert the second DF with the same column 'port' right after and then have the mode/onlineCounter/Status and vlan

Comment: What is the structure of the second dataframe?

Comment: answer edited with more information, I guess the best way is to concatenate on index 1 as the column 'port' is the same for both

Comment: am i correct in understanding that you have the one table with 4 columns and you just want to update more information where port is the only column matched between the two? So you would want `['port', 'Address', 'Ipaddress', 'Plateform', 'mode', 'onlineCount', 'status', ...]`

Comment: this is correct !

Comment: See update, you should be good to go

Comment: thanks, tried the header is now present on the excel however no data are being reported

df_merge_col = pd.merge(dataframe,dataframe_cdp, on='port')

Comment: check that both dataframes have values before you merge. I expanded my answer to show exactly what i did.

Comment: both has data, by I believe the issue might be with the data type? one Dictionaire, other list? https://i.gyazo.com/1de811492e1c8614cffe773a0be27a3a.png - according to the Pandas doc, the pd.merge requiered DataFrame value but no idea how to convert my dataframe_cdp yet

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric()` to make sure both port columns are numeric

Comment: It keep saying that my Dataframe is empty, while when I print the df1 and df2 I cant see the output, but not when I merge those using print(pd.merge(df, df2, on='port')) pd.to_numeric would only work for Num but I have some str as well on the output

Comment: Try only doing the one column `df['port'] = pd.to_numeric(df['port'])`

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat so that give some indication on what type of DF this is!

Comment: got it finally working using the merge and specifying the how='outer' !! thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the columns afterward with

```
dataframe.columns = re_table.header
```

or in the declaration

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fsm_results, columns=re_table.header)
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

> **columns** : Index or array-like
>
> Column labels to use for resulting frame. Will default to RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, …, n) if no column labels are provided

To merge the two tables together based on the `port` column, you can use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Check to make sure the `port` columns are the same data type. You can use `pd.to_numeric()` as shown below where I set `port` to be strings in the first dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['46', '98 f2 b3 4e 7c b0',  '172.27.254.212',  'HP J9774A'],
    ['48', '',  '172.27.254.210',  'Cisco IOS'],
    ['48', '24 e9 b3 a0 c8 80',  '172.27.254.210',  'Cisco IOS'],
], columns=['port', 'Address', 'Ipaddress', 'Plateform'])
df1['port'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['port'])
print(df1)
#    port            Address       Ipaddress  Plateform
# 0    46  98 f2 b3 4e 7c b0  172.27.254.212  HP J9774A
# 1    48                     172.27.254.210  Cisco IOS
# 2    48  24 e9 b3 a0 c8 80  172.27.254.210  Cisco IOS

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [46, 100, 'Active'],
    [48, 42, 'Inactive']
], columns=['port', 'onlineCount', 'status'])
print(df2)
#    port  onlineCount    status
# 0    46          100    Active
# 1    48           42  Inactive

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='port'))
#    port            Address    ...    onlineCount    status
# 0    46  98 f2 b3 4e 7c b0    ...            100    Active
# 1    48                       ...             42  Inactive
# 2    48  24 e9 b3 a0 c8 80    ...             42  Inactive
```

More information can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) regarding ways to combine dataframes.

Comment: Thank Brian it did work! now I have to merge the 2 dataframe ( I have the first script generating some Excel ) and this one who you just resolved - the code looks like this:

```
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(interfaceDict).T # transpose the tables so interfaces are in a column
        dataframe.sort_values(by=['port'], inplace=True) # sort the values by the "port" column we made
        dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index to match this
```
interfaceDict is the first dataframe, shall I just do:

```
I believe I would need to use pd.concat?

Comment: Can you add that information to your question along with some data from it? `pd.concat` can probably take care of it, but I'm not 100% sure without seeing the structure.